# Javascript code for autocomplete/autofill slowing the survey

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, qualtrics

Working on a Qualtrics Survey, I have added a JS code to some of the questions for auto completion of the names, The code is as shown below.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
/*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/

    var textOptions = [
        "Aadi Shah",
        "Aakash Agrawal",
        "Aakash Gupta",
        "Aakash Jaiswal"
    ];

    jQuery('.InputText').autocomplete({source:textOptions});
});
```

But inside the textOptions array I have close to 5000 names which slowing down the survey as whenever I enter the text in the text field it becomes unresponsive. Is there any way of optimizing this code?

Comment: You can save these name in external js/json file and on page load do call to fetch this json data

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that the data entry retrieval is cached to save on I/O
2. Use some kind of debounce and throttling. Essentially instead of showing you options on each keypress, the request should go after every 2 or 3 keys, thus having a better match as well as reducing the processing by multiple orders of magnitude.

Please check following links for further information

[Debounce Example with jQuery](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/)

[Throttling and Debounce](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-646d076d0a44)

[jQuery Autocomplete debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963299/jquery-auto-complete-request-throttling)